# IDA decompiler: show a "for" loop instead of a "while", is it possible?

Tags: ida, decompiler

I'm reversing an embedded code, and faced with this "while" loop in while decompiling:

[image: A while loop that I need to be shown as "for" loop]

It's more readable for me if a "for" loop be shown instead a  "while", i.e.:

```
while (1)                  -->            for (i = 0; i < 2; i ++) 
{                          -->            {
  "SOME EXPRESSION"        -->              "SOME EXPRESSION"
  if (++i >= 2) return;    -->            
}                          -->            }
```

Is it possible to ask IDA Decompiler to show this loop in my own way?

Answer (score 3):

If you write a Hex-Rays plugin to change the `while` loop to a `for` loop yourself, then yes, you can do it. If you're looking for something more like the ability to right-click on the loop and click `Display as for loop`, nothing like that is built in.

Comment: @ Rolf Rolles Thanks for your answer Rolf. Do you know any plugin for that purpose or or any"like but not exact" sample or some python/IDC APIs to help me write my own?